# « Se souvenir », « se rappeler », « remémorer » et « se remémorer »

Tags: vocabulaire

Quels sont les points communs et les différences entre ces verbes ? Je me suis reporté [ici](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=783689) qui n'aborde pas « (se) remémorer ». Du reste, ces définitions-ci ne détaillent ni n'exposent ces différences.

En outre, la définition offerte de se remémorer est proprement se rappeler.
Néanmoins, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=se+rappeler%2Cse+rem%C3%A9morer&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cse%20rappeler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cse%20rem%C3%A9morer%3B%2Cc0) manifeste une  différence marquante de fréquence de leur usage. Pourquoi ?

[Se souvenir](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/se_souvenir/73992?q=souvenir#73163) :

> Garder la trace de quelqu'un, de quelque chose dans la mémoire, se le rappeler : *Je me souviens de cette affaire. Il se souvint qu'il devait partir.*

[Se rappeler](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/se_rappeler/66512?q=rappeler#65763) :

> Avoir présent à l'esprit, dans la mémoire, le souvenir de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose : *Se rappeler très bien ses grands-parents.*

[Remémorer](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/rem%C3%A9morer/67988?q=rememorer#67235) :

> Rappeler quelque chose à quelqu'un, le lui remettre en mémoire : *Ce village lui remémorait sa jeunesse.*

[Se remémorer](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/se_rem%C3%A9morer/67989?q=rememorer#67236)

Comment: Merci de chercher dans des dictionnaires, et de reporter les définitions trouvées. Pour comprendre les nuances il n'y a pas de meilleur moyen que de lire plusieurs définitions et analyser plusieurs exemples. Ce site n'est pas un substitut aux dictionnaires. Il serait bien plus constructif de donner un exemple pour lequel tu ne sais pas choisir.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Merci de vos conseils. Est-ce mieux ?

Comment: Le Larousse est vraiment pauvre tu devrais utiliser les [ressources du cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rem%C3%A9morer), il y a plein d'exemples.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_souvenir) est peut-être plus simple que le cnrtl pour un non francophone (et bien mieux que Larousse).

Answer (score 1):

- Je me souviens de vous, comment pourrais-je vous avoir oublié ?
- Allo, je vous rappelle que nous avions rendez-vous, vous souvenez-vous ?
- Je me remémore les temps anciens de ma jeunesse en vous regardant.

I do not believe that "remémorer" could be used alone.